# Restore the default Android settings app

Tags: settings, hebrew

We just got a new Android smartphone. It is an LG L1 II E410i. The provider is [HOT mobile](https://www.hotmobile.co.il/HOTmobile_en/Pages/default.aspx).

The phone's default language is Hebrew, and I can't seem to change it. The normal Android settings app is not available - they seem to have replaced it with their own.

Is it possible to get the settings app back?

Comment: Try this link first - http://www.lg.com/uk/support-mobile/lg-LGE410I#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this link first - [LG L1 Support Page](http://www.lg.com/uk/support-mobile/lg-LGE410I#) and checkout the manuals provided. If you don't find what you need then try `Live Chat` provided below in the same page to ask them directly about this problem. If no chat agents available at that time try emailing them.